# Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) when booting from S3C6410 board

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I have a S3C6410 board. The default Linux in the package is 2.6.28 and working fine. I want to upgrade it with more recent kernel. I grabbed buildroot 2012.11 edition. Then I get the default config file in the DVD and compiled the kernel 3.6.8 with that. Boot loader and root file system are the same old ones. Now when I boot the kernel I got this error:

```
VFS: Cannot open root device "mtdblock2" or unknown-block(0,0): error -19
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
1f00            8192 mtdblock0  (driver?)
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[<c0018528>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xf0) from [<c03977d4>] (panic+0x78/0x1b8)
[<c03977d4>] (panic+0x78/0x1b8) from [<c04f0bbc>] (mount_block_root+0x178/0x22c)
[<c04f0bbc>] (mount_block_root+0x178/0x22c) from [<c04f0e54>] (mount_root+0xe8/0x10c)
[<c04f0e54>] (mount_root+0xe8/0x10c) from [<c04f0fcc>] (prepare_namespace+0x154/0x1ac)
[<c04f0fcc>] (prepare_namespace+0x154/0x1ac) from [<c04f0874>] (kernel_init+0x16c/0x1a8)
[<c04f0874>] (kernel_init+0x16c/0x1a8) from [<c001424c>] (kernel_thread_exit+0x0/0x8)
```

This my kernel config file:

```
CONFIG_ARM=y
CONFIG_SYS_SUPPORTS_APM_EMULATION=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_GPIO=y
CONFIG_MMU=y
CONFIG_NO_IOPORT=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_HARDIRQS=y
CONFIG_STACKTRACE_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_HAVE_LATENCYTOP_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_LOCKDEP_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_TRACE_IRQFLAGS_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_HARDIRQS_SW_RESEND=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_IRQ_PROBE=y
CONFIG_RWSEM_GENERIC_SPINLOCK=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_HWEIGHT=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_CALIBRATE_DELAY=y
CONFIG_ZONE_DMA=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_HARDIRQS_NO__DO_IRQ=y
CONFIG_VECTORS_BASE=0xffff0000
CONFIG_DEFCONFIG_LIST="/lib/modules/$UNAME_RELEASE/.config"

CONFIG_EXPERIMENTAL=y
CONFIG_BROKEN_ON_SMP=y
CONFIG_INIT_ENV_ARG_LIMIT=32
CONFIG_LOCALVERSION="-EmbedSky"
CONFIG_SYSVIPC=y
CONFIG_SYSVIPC_SYSCTL=y
CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT=17
CONFIG_NAMESPACES=y
CONFIG_SYSCTL=y
CONFIG_UID16=y
CONFIG_SYSCTL_SYSCALL=y
CONFIG_KALLSYMS=y
CONFIG_HOTPLUG=y
CONFIG_PRINTK=y
CONFIG_BUG=y
CONFIG_ELF_CORE=y
CONFIG_BASE_FULL=y
CONFIG_FUTEX=y
CONFIG_ANON_INODES=y
CONFIG_EPOLL=y
CONFIG_SIGNALFD=y
CONFIG_TIMERFD=y
CONFIG_EVENTFD=y
CONFIG_SHMEM=y
CONFIG_AIO=y
CONFIG_VM_EVENT_COUNTERS=y
CONFIG_SLUB_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_SLUB=y
CONFIG_HAVE_OPROFILE=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KPROBES=y
CONFIG_HAVE_KRETPROBES=y
CONFIG_HAVE_CLK=y
CONFIG_HAVE_GENERIC_DMA_COHERENT=y
CONFIG_SLABINFO=y
CONFIG_RT_MUTEXES=y
CONFIG_BASE_SMALL=0
CONFIG_MODULES=y
CONFIG_MODULE_UNLOAD=y
CONFIG_KMOD=y
CONFIG_BLOCK=y
CONFIG_LBD=y
CONFIG_LSF=y

CONFIG_IOSCHED_NOOP=y
CONFIG_IOSCHED_AS=y
CONFIG_IOSCHED_DEADLINE=y
CONFIG_IOSCHED_CFQ=y
CONFIG_DEFAULT_NOOP=y
CONFIG_DEFAULT_IOSCHED="noop"
CONFIG_CLASSIC_RCU=y

CONFIG_ARCH_S3C64XX=y
CONFIG_PLAT_S3C64XX=y
CONFIG_CPU_S3C6400_INIT=y
CONFIG_CPU_S3C6400_CLOCK=y
CONFIG_S3C64XX_SETUP_I2C0=y
CONFIG_S3C64XX_DEV_FIMC0=y
CONFIG_S3C64XX_DEV_FIMC1=y
CONFIG_S3C64XX_SETUP_FIMC0=y
CONFIG_S3C64XX_SETUP_FIMC1=y
CONFIG_NONE_PWM=y
CONFIG_PLAT_S3C=y

CONFIG_S3C_BOOT_ERROR_RESET=y

CONFIG_S3C_LOWLEVEL_UART_PORT=0
CONFIG_SPLIT_ROOT_FILESYSTEM=y
CONFIG_S3C_GPIO_SPACE=0
CONFIG_S3C_GPIO_TRACK=y
CONFIG_S3C_GPIO_PULL_UPDOWN=y
CONFIG_S3C_GPIO_CFG_S3C24XX=y
CONFIG_S3C_GPIO_CFG_S3C64XX=y
CONFIG_S3C_DEV_HSMMC=y
CONFIG_S3C_DEV_HSMMC1=y
CONFIG_S3C_DEV_HSMMC2=y
CONFIG_S3C_DMA_PL080=y
CONFIG_CPU_S3C6410=y
CONFIG_S3C6410_SETUP_SDHCI=y
CONFIG_MACH_SMDK6410=y

CONFIG_SMDK6410_SD_CH0=y
CONFIG_SMDK6410_SD_CH1=y
CONFIG_SMDK6410_SD_CH2=y

CONFIG_CPU_32=y
CONFIG_CPU_V6=y
CONFIG_CPU_32v6K=y
CONFIG_CPU_32v6=y
CONFIG_CPU_ABRT_EV6=y
CONFIG_CPU_PABRT_NOIFAR=y
CONFIG_CPU_CACHE_V6=y
CONFIG_CPU_CACHE_VIPT=y
CONFIG_CPU_COPY_V6=y
CONFIG_CPU_TLB_V6=y
CONFIG_CPU_HAS_ASID=y
CONFIG_CPU_CP15=y
CONFIG_CPU_CP15_MMU=y

CONFIG_ARM_THUMB=y
CONFIG_ARM_VIC=y
CONFIG_DMABOUNCE=y

CONFIG_VMSPLIT_3G=y
CONFIG_PAGE_OFFSET=0xC0000000
CONFIG_HZ=200
CONFIG_AEABI=y
CONFIG_OABI_COMPAT=y
CONFIG_ARCH_FLATMEM_HAS_HOLES=y
CONFIG_SELECT_MEMORY_MODEL=y
CONFIG_FLATMEM_MANUAL=y
CONFIG_FLATMEM=y
CONFIG_FLAT_NODE_MEM_MAP=y
CONFIG_PAGEFLAGS_EXTENDED=y
CONFIG_SPLIT_PTLOCK_CPUS=4
CONFIG_ZONE_DMA_FLAG=1
CONFIG_BOUNCE=y
CONFIG_VIRT_TO_BUS=y
CONFIG_UNEVICTABLE_LRU=y
CONFIG_ALIGNMENT_TRAP=y

CONFIG_ZBOOT_ROM_TEXT=0
CONFIG_ZBOOT_ROM_BSS=0
CONFIG_CMDLINE="root=/dev/mtdblock2 rootfstype=yaffs2 init=/linuxrc console=ttySAC0  mem=128M"

CONFIG_FPE_NWFPE=y
CONFIG_VFP=y

CONFIG_BINFMT_ELF=y
CONFIG_HAVE_AOUT=y

CONFIG_ARCH_SUSPEND_POSSIBLE=y
CONFIG_NET=y

CONFIG_UNIX=y
CONFIG_XFRM=y
CONFIG_INET=y
CONFIG_IP_FIB_HASH=y
CONFIG_IP_PNP=y
CONFIG_IP_PNP_DHCP=y
CONFIG_IP_PNP_BOOTP=y
CONFIG_INET_XFRM_MODE_TRANSPORT=y
CONFIG_INET_XFRM_MODE_TUNNEL=y
CONFIG_INET_XFRM_MODE_BEET=y
CONFIG_INET_DIAG=y
CONFIG_INET_TCP_DIAG=y
CONFIG_TCP_CONG_CUBIC=y
CONFIG_DEFAULT_TCP_CONG="cubic"

CONFIG_WIRELESS=y
CONFIG_CFG80211=y
CONFIG_WIRELESS_EXT=y
CONFIG_MAC80211=m

CONFIG_MAC80211_RC_PID=y
CONFIG_MAC80211_RC_MINSTREL=y
CONFIG_MAC80211_RC_DEFAULT_PID=y
CONFIG_MAC80211_RC_DEFAULT="pid"

CONFIG_UEVENT_HELPER_PATH="/sbin/hotplug"
CONFIG_STANDALONE=y
CONFIG_PREVENT_FIRMWARE_BUILD=y
CONFIG_FW_LOADER=y
CONFIG_FIRMWARE_IN_KERNEL=y
CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE=""
CONFIG_MTD=y
CONFIG_MTD_PARTITIONS=y
CONFIG_MTD_CMDLINE_PARTS=y

CONFIG_MTD_CHAR=y
CONFIG_MTD_BLKDEVS=y
CONFIG_MTD_BLOCK=y

CONFIG_MTD_MAP_BANK_WIDTH_1=y
CONFIG_MTD_MAP_BANK_WIDTH_2=y
CONFIG_MTD_MAP_BANK_WIDTH_4=y
CONFIG_MTD_CFI_I1=y
CONFIG_MTD_CFI_I2=y

CONFIG_MTD_NAND=y
CONFIG_MTD_NAND_IDS=y
CONFIG_MTD_NAND_S3C=y

CONFIG_BLK_DEV=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_LOOP=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM_COUNT=16
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM_SIZE=8192
CONFIG_MISC_DEVICES=y
CONFIG_HAVE_IDE=y

CONFIG_SCSI=y
CONFIG_SCSI_DMA=y
CONFIG_SCSI_PROC_FS=y

CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SD=y
CONFIG_CHR_DEV_SG=y

CONFIG_SCSI_WAIT_SCAN=m

CONFIG_SCSI_LOWLEVEL=y
CONFIG_NETDEVICES=y
CONFIG_NET_ETHERNET=y
CONFIG_MII=y
CONFIG_DM9000AEP=y

CONFIG_WLAN_80211=y
CONFIG_ZD1211RW=m
CONFIG_ZD1211RW_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_RT2X00=m
CONFIG_RT73USB=m
CONFIG_RT2X00_LIB_USB=m
CONFIG_RT2X00_LIB=m
CONFIG_RT2X00_LIB_FIRMWARE=y
CONFIG_RT2X00_LIB_CRYPTO=y
CONFIG_RT2X00_DEBUG=y

CONFIG_INPUT=y

CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSEDEV=y
CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSEDEV_PSAUX=y
CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSEDEV_SCREEN_X=1024
CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSEDEV_SCREEN_Y=768
CONFIG_INPUT_EVDEV=y

CONFIG_INPUT_KEYBOARD=y
CONFIG_KEYPAD_S3C64XX=y
CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSE=y
CONFIG_INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN=y
CONFIG_TOUCHSCREEN_S3C64XX=y

CONFIG_SERIO=y
CONFIG_SERIO_SERPORT=y

CONFIG_VT=y
CONFIG_CONSOLE_TRANSLATIONS=y
CONFIG_VT_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_HW_CONSOLE=y

CONFIG_SERIAL_SAMSUNG=y
CONFIG_SERIAL_SAMSUNG_UARTS=4
CONFIG_SERIAL_SAMSUNG_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_SERIAL_S3C6400=y
CONFIG_SERIAL_CORE=y
CONFIG_SERIAL_CORE_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_UNIX98_PTYS=y
CONFIG_S3C_MEM=y
CONFIG_I2C=y
CONFIG_I2C_BOARDINFO=y
CONFIG_I2C_CHARDEV=y
CONFIG_I2C_HELPER_AUTO=y

CONFIG_I2C_S3C2410=y

CONFIG_AT24=y
CONFIG_ARCH_REQUIRE_GPIOLIB=y
CONFIG_GPIOLIB=y

CONFIG_HWMON=y
CONFIG_WATCHDOG=y

CONFIG_S3C2410_WATCHDOG=y

CONFIG_SSB_POSSIBLE=y

CONFIG_VIDEO_DEV=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_V4L2_COMMON=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_ALLOW_V4L1=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_V4L1_COMPAT=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_MEDIA=y

CONFIG_MEDIA_TUNER=y
CONFIG_MEDIA_TUNER_SIMPLE=y
CONFIG_MEDIA_TUNER_TDA8290=y
CONFIG_MEDIA_TUNER_TDA9887=y
CONFIG_MEDIA_TUNER_TEA5761=y
CONFIG_MEDIA_TUNER_TEA5767=y
CONFIG_MEDIA_TUNER_MT20XX=y
CONFIG_MEDIA_TUNER_XC2028=y
CONFIG_MEDIA_TUNER_XC5000=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_V4L2=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_V4L1=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_CAPTURE_DRIVERS=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_FIXED_MINOR_RANGES=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_HELPER_CHIPS_AUTO=y
CONFIG_V4L_USB_DRIVERS=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA=y
CONFIG_USB_M5602=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_CONEX=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_ETOMS=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_FINEPIX=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_MARS=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_OV519=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_PAC207=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_PAC7311=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_SONIXB=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_SONIXJ=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_SPCA500=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_SPCA501=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_SPCA505=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_SPCA506=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_SPCA508=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_SPCA561=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_STK014=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_SUNPLUS=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_T613=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_TV8532=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_VC032X=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA_ZC3XX=y
CONFIG_USB_ZC0301=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_SAMSUNG=y

CONFIG_VIDEO_FIMC=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_FIMC_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_OV965X=y
CONFIG_OV965X_VGA=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_FIMC_CAM_CH=0
CONFIG_VIDEO_FIMC_CAM_RESET=1
CONFIG_VIDEO_POST=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_MFC10=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_MFC_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_JPEG=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_TV=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_ROTATOR=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_G2D=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_G3D=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_CMM=y

CONFIG_VIDEO_SAMSUNG_MEMSIZE_FIMC=10240
CONFIG_VIDEO_SAMSUNG_MEMSIZE_POST=8192
CONFIG_VIDEO_SAMSUNG_MEMSIZE_TV=8192
CONFIG_VIDEO_SAMSUNG_MEMSIZE_MFC=6144
CONFIG_VIDEO_SAMSUNG_MEMSIZE_JPEG=4096
CONFIG_VIDEO_SAMSUNG_MEMSIZE_CMM=8192

CONFIG_FB=y
CONFIG_FB_CFB_FILLRECT=y
CONFIG_FB_CFB_COPYAREA=y
CONFIG_FB_CFB_IMAGEBLIT=y

CONFIG_FB_S3C=y
CONFIG_FB_S3C_LCD800480=y
CONFIG_FB_S3C_BPP=y
CONFIG_FB_S3C_BPP_16=y
CONFIG_FB_S3C_NUM=4
CONFIG_FB_S3C_DOUBLE_BUFFERING=y

CONFIG_DUMMY_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_FONTS=y
CONFIG_FONT_8x16=y
CONFIG_LOGO=y
CONFIG_LOGO_LINUX_CLUT224=y
CONFIG_SOUND=y
CONFIG_SOUND_OSS_CORE=y
CONFIG_SND=y
CONFIG_SND_TIMER=y
CONFIG_SND_PCM=y
CONFIG_SND_OSSEMUL=y
CONFIG_SND_MIXER_OSS=y
CONFIG_SND_PCM_OSS=y
CONFIG_SND_PCM_OSS_PLUGINS=y
CONFIG_SND_SUPPORT_OLD_API=y
CONFIG_SND_VERBOSE_PROCFS=y
CONFIG_SND_VMASTER=y
CONFIG_SND_AC97_CODEC=y
CONFIG_SND_DRIVERS=y
CONFIG_SND_ARM=y
CONFIG_SND_USB=y
CONFIG_SND_SOC=y
CONFIG_SND_SOC_AC97_BUS=y

CONFIG_SND_S3C64XX_SOC=y
CONFIG_SND_S3C64XX_SOC_SMDK6410_WM9713=y
CONFIG_SOUND_WM9713_INPUT_STREAM_MIC=y
CONFIG_SND_S3C6410_SOC_AC97=y
CONFIG_SND_SOC_WM9713=y
CONFIG_AC97_BUS=y
CONFIG_HID_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_HID=y
CONFIG_HID_DEBUG=y

CONFIG_USB_HID=y

CONFIG_HID_A4TECH=y
CONFIG_HID_APPLE=y
CONFIG_HID_BELKIN=y
CONFIG_HID_BRIGHT=y
CONFIG_HID_CHERRY=y
CONFIG_HID_CHICONY=y
CONFIG_HID_CYPRESS=y
CONFIG_HID_DELL=y
CONFIG_HID_EZKEY=y
CONFIG_HID_GYRATION=y
CONFIG_HID_LOGITECH=y
CONFIG_HID_MICROSOFT=y
CONFIG_HID_MONTEREY=y
CONFIG_HID_PANTHERLORD=y
CONFIG_HID_PETALYNX=y
CONFIG_HID_SAMSUNG=y
CONFIG_HID_SONY=y
CONFIG_HID_SUNPLUS=y
CONFIG_USB_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_USB_ARCH_HAS_HCD=y
CONFIG_USB_ARCH_HAS_OHCI=y
CONFIG_USB=y

CONFIG_USB_DEVICEFS=y
CONFIG_USB_DEVICE_CLASS=y

CONFIG_USB_OHCI_HCD=y
CONFIG_USB_OHCI_LITTLE_ENDIAN=y

CONFIG_USB_STORAGE=y

CONFIG_USB_SERIAL=y
CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_PL2303=m

CONFIG_USB_GADGET=y
CONFIG_USB_GADGET_VBUS_DRAW=2
CONFIG_USB_GADGET_SELECTED=y
CONFIG_USB_GADGET_S3C_OTGD=y

CONFIG_USB_S3C_OTGD=y
CONFIG_USB_GADGET_S3C_OTGD_DMA_MODE=y
CONFIG_USB_GADGET_DUALSPEED=y
CONFIG_USB_GADGETFS=m
CONFIG_USB_FILE_STORAGE=m
CONFIG_MMC=y

CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK=y
CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK_BOUNCE=y
CONFIG_SDIO_UART=y

CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI=y
CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI_S3C=y
CONFIG_RTC_LIB=y
CONFIG_RTC_CLASS=y
CONFIG_RTC_HCTOSYS=y
CONFIG_RTC_HCTOSYS_DEVICE="rtc0"

CONFIG_RTC_INTF_SYSFS=y
CONFIG_RTC_INTF_PROC=y
CONFIG_RTC_INTF_DEV=y

CONFIG_RTC_DRV_S3C=y

CONFIG_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_FILE_LOCKING=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_ACL=y

CONFIG_FAT_FS=y
CONFIG_MSDOS_FS=y
CONFIG_VFAT_FS=y
CONFIG_FAT_DEFAULT_CODEPAGE=936
CONFIG_FAT_DEFAULT_IOCHARSET="utf-8"

CONFIG_PROC_FS=y
CONFIG_PROC_SYSCTL=y
CONFIG_PROC_PAGE_MONITOR=y
CONFIG_SYSFS=y
CONFIG_TMPFS=y
CONFIG_TMPFS_POSIX_ACL=y

CONFIG_YAFFS_FS=y
CONFIG_YAFFS_YAFFS1=y
CONFIG_YAFFS_YAFFS2=y
CONFIG_YAFFS_AUTO_YAFFS2=y
CONFIG_CRAMFS=y
CONFIG_NETWORK_FILESYSTEMS=y
CONFIG_NFS_FS=y
CONFIG_NFS_V3=y
CONFIG_NFS_V3_ACL=y
CONFIG_NFS_V4=y
CONFIG_ROOT_NFS=y
CONFIG_LOCKD=y
CONFIG_LOCKD_V4=y
CONFIG_NFS_ACL_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_NFS_COMMON=y
CONFIG_SUNRPC=y
CONFIG_SUNRPC_GSS=y
CONFIG_RPCSEC_GSS_KRB5=y

CONFIG_MSDOS_PARTITION=y
CONFIG_NLS=y
CONFIG_NLS_DEFAULT="iso8859-1"
CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_437=y
CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_936=y
CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_950=y
CONFIG_NLS_ASCII=y
CONFIG_NLS_ISO8859_1=y
CONFIG_NLS_UTF8=y

CONFIG_FRAME_WARN=1024
CONFIG_DEBUG_BUGVERBOSE=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_MEMORY_INIT=y
CONFIG_FRAME_POINTER=y
CONFIG_HAVE_FUNCTION_TRACER=y

CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_KGDB=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_S3C_UART=0

CONFIG_CRYPTO=y

CONFIG_CRYPTO_ALGAPI=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_ALGAPI2=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_AEAD2=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_BLKCIPHER=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_BLKCIPHER2=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_HASH2=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_RNG2=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_MANAGER=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_MANAGER2=y

CONFIG_CRYPTO_CBC=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_ECB=y

CONFIG_CRYPTO_MD5=y

CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_ARC4=y
CONFIG_CRYPTO_DES=y

CONFIG_CRYPTO_HW=y

CONFIG_BITREVERSE=y
CONFIG_CRC_ITU_T=y
CONFIG_CRC32=y
CONFIG_ZLIB_INFLATE=y
CONFIG_PLIST=y
CONFIG_HAS_IOMEM=y
CONFIG_HAS_DMA=y
```

It seems the problem is MTD. But MTD support is enabled in kernel. Am I missing something?
I have installed bootloader, kernel and root file system in the NAND flash. If I want to store root file system to SD card with ext2 file system, what I should change? How this line would change?

```
CONFIG_CMDLINE="root=/dev/mtdblock2 rootfstype=yaffs2 init=/linuxrc console=ttySAC0  mem=128M"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable the ext2 filesystem in your kernel config:

```
CONFIG_EXT2_FS=y
```

Comment: Run `make menuconfig` and enable the option (it is called `CONFIG_EXT2_FS`. Editing the `.config` file also works, but only on odd Fridays with new moon (or if the editor knows exactly what they are doing). After editing by hand, a `make oldconfig` is **mandatory**.

Answer (score 2):

You should post your entire kernel boot log if you want anyone to help you on this. Apparently, the /dev/mtdblock2 device does not exists, which probably indicates that your kernel has not been given a partition for your flash.

Also, this question has absolutely nothing to do with Buildroot, it's purely a kernel configuration / kernel command line problem.