# Beaglebone black uImage boot issues

Tags: linux-kernel, beagleboneblack, u-boot

I am trying to boot the beaglebone black using the uImage file that I created using the mkimage command. There is a emmc to sd image flasher package available online which has a uImage in it and also other required files (https://elinux.org/BeagleBone_Black_Extracting_eMMC_contents), I followed this website and created a flasher card of the uImage that I made using mkimage utility.

I am getting the following error during boot from SD card having that uImage:

```
U-Boot SPL 2016.01-00763-g3faf221 (Jan 29 2016 - 20:47:08)
Trying to boot from MMC
Card doesn't support part_switch
MMC partition switch failed
*** Warning - MMC partition switch failed, using default environment

reading u-boot.img
reading u-boot.img


U-Boot 2016.01-00763-g3faf221 (Jan 29 2016 - 20:47:08 +0000)

       Watchdog enabled
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  512 MiB
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

Net:   <ethaddr> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC
cpsw, usb_ether
Press SPACE to abort autoboot in 2 seconds
=> set sdboot 1
=> boot
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
Scanning mmc 0:1...
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
SD/MMC found on device 0
reading boot.scr
** Unable to read file boot.scr **
reading uEnv.txt
235 bytes read in 5 ms (45.9 KiB/s)
Loaded environment from uEnv.txt
Importing environment from mmc ...
Running uenvcmd ...
reading uImage
5497536 bytes read in 302 ms (17.4 MiB/s)
reading /am335x-boneblack.dtb
25926 bytes read in 8 ms (3.1 MiB/s)
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 82000000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux kernel
   Created:      2015-09-07  21:47:16 UTC
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    5497472 Bytes = 5.2 MiB
   Load Address: 80008000
   Entry Point:  80008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 81ff0000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x81ff0000
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 8fff6000, end 8ffff545 ... OK

Starting kernel ...

Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
[    0.177572] omap2_mbox_probe: platform not supported
[    0.333923] tps65217-bl tps65217-bl: no platform data provided
[    0.397544] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.9: slot #0: No cape found
[    0.434652] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.9: slot #1: No cape found
[    0.471760] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.9: slot #2: No cape found
[    0.508869] bone-capemgr bone_capemgr.9: slot #3: No cape found
[    0.528815] omap_hsmmc mmc.5: of_parse_phandle_with_args of 'reset' failed
[    0.591166] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: pin 44e10854 already requested by 44e10800.pinmux; cannot claim for gpio-leds.8
[    0.602845] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: pin-21 (gpio-leds.8) status -22
[    0.610128] pinctrl-single 44e10800.pinmux: could not request pin 21 on device pinctrl-single
[    0.686675] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[    0.695344] [<c0010f5d>] (unwind_backtrace+0x1/0x98) from [<c04994c3>] (panic+0x5b/0x158)
[    0.703882] [<c04994c3>] (panic+0x5b/0x158) from [<c07bc94b>] (mount_block_root+0xf7/0x178)
[    0.712595] [<c07bc94b>] (mount_block_root+0xf7/0x178) from [<c07bcb09>] (mount_root+0x95/0xb0)
[    0.721676] [<c07bcb09>] (mount_root+0x95/0xb0) from [<c07bcbef>] (prepare_namespace+0xcb/0x11c)
[    0.730836] [<c07bcbef>] (prepare_namespace+0xcb/0x11c) from [<c0495aff>] (kernel_init+0x7/0x98)
[    0.740007] [<c0495aff>] (kernel_init+0x7/0x98) from [<c000c7fd>] (ret_from_fork+0x11/0x34)
```

Any help will be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) when booting from S3C6410 board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314036/unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0-when-booting-from-s3c6410-board)

Answer (score 0):

The kernel cannot find the root partition. The kernel command line is set in U-Boot via the environment variable bootargs.